# Can't erase multiple elements inside SDL Poll Events

Tags: c++, for-loop, iteration, sdl

I'm using SDL for event and window handling, however I can't seem to erase multiple elements in a for loop. I have two elements, and it prints out "Testing" twice when hitting the delete key - perfect! However, when both elements are "picked" (bool), it only removes the first element, and not the second.

This function is being called inside SDL's Poll Events loop:

```
static inline void tickEditorKeyFunctions(CBevent e)
    {
        if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_w:                
                break;
            case SDLK_s:
                break;
            case SDLK_a:
                break;
            case SDLK_d:
                break;
            case SDLK_LCTRL:
                break;
            case SDLK_LSHIFT:
                break;
            case SDLK_DELETE:
                for (CBuint i = 0; i < _scene->static_meshes.size(); i++)
               {
                if (_scene->static_meshes[i]->_picked)
                    _scene->static_meshes.erase(_scene->static_meshes.begin() + i);
                std::cout << "Testing" << std::endl;
            }

            _pick_list.clear();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a clean and rebuild? Your `for` loop looks fine...

Comment: Yes I have. I think it's something to do with SDL's event callback system :/

Comment: @William it's nothing to do with SDL, and all to do with how collections and iterators work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If static_meshes is an STL collection, you need to look at the [Erase Remove Idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to remove items.

Try

```
_scene->static_meshes.erase(std::remove_if(_scene->static_meshes.begin(),
                                           _scene->static_meshes.end(),
                                           [](TYPEOF _scene->static_meshes *item){return item->picked;}), 
                           _scene->static_meshes.end());
```

Comment: Ah yes, I took a look at this idiom but i wasn't sure how it would work with my STL container. Thank you for providing source code, I'll definitely try this out later! I'm guessing this doesn't need to be inside a for loop?

Comment: is the TYPEOF variable an operator?

Comment: No that type of was for you to replace, and no it doesn't need to be in a loop

Comment: I love you. This is the best solution yet, thank you ever so much sir!

Answer (score 0):

If your `_scene->static_meshes` is an STL container (e.g. vector), `erase` destroys iterator and changes size. If array was `[0, 1, 2]` and you erased index `1`, - there is no longer index `2` in this array, it now contains only 2 elements. `size` will be reduced and your second iteration may not be performed at all, or be performed at wrong element. Possible solution is not incrementing `i` after erasing element. Surely there are other ways to do so.

Comment: Yes I thought this would be the problem actually. It has to be the problem, surely.